# How to select non-NA values by group unless only NAs

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select non-NA values by id and by year for both variables v1 and v2 (in my actual dataset there are more than two variables like v1 and v2), unless there are only NAs.

I also want to set it so that if values by id and year conflict, I choose the last row.

```
> id<- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5,5)
> year<-c(2014, 2014, 2019, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2019)
> v1<- c("a", NA, NA, NA, "b", "a", "b", NA, NA, "c", NA, "a", NA)
> v2<- c(NA, "x", "y", "z", "z","z","z", "x", NA, NA, "x", "x", "x")
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, year, v1, v2))
> df
   id year   v1   v2
1   1 2014    a <NA>
2   1 2014 <NA>    x
3   1 2019 <NA>    y
4   2 2014 <NA>    z
5   2 2014    b    z
6   2 2014    a    z
7   2 2020    b    z
8   3 2018 <NA>    x
9   3 2018 <NA> <NA>
10  4 2017    c <NA>
11  4 2018 <NA>    x
12  5 2019    a    x
13  5 2019 <NA>    x
```

Here is what I want my result to look like:

```
 id year   v1   v2
1   1 2014    a    x
3   1 2019 <NA>    y
6   2 2014    a    z
7   2 2020    b    z
8   3 2018 <NA>    x
10  4 2017    c <NA>
11  4 2018 <NA>    x
12  5 2019    a    x
```

I was trying to use dplyr with group_by, but having issues getting it to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After grouping, you can try summarizing and taking the `last` value after removing `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarise(v1 = last(na.omit(v1)), 
            v2 = last(na.omit(v2)))
```

To use `summarise` with all columns (except those used in grouping), you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarise_all(~ last(na.omit(.)))
```

**Output**

```
  id    year  v1    v2   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     2014  a     x    
2 1     2019  NA    y    
3 2     2014  a     z    
4 2     2020  b     z    
5 3     2018  NA    x    
6 4     2017  c     NA   
7 4     2018  NA    x    
8 5     2019  a     x
```

Comment: This solution works, which is great - I want to note, in case other people have this issue, that this solution deleted NAs until I unloaded the package data.table.